# What can we do with questions 'bumped' by Community bot?

Tags: discussion

The home page of Arduino SE and the Active tab of the Questions page have old questions modified by the Community bot. The bot periodically bumps some old questions to our attention.

How can we resolve those bumped questions to prevent the bot to bump them again and again?

Answer (score 2):

We should read, evaluate and handle those bumped Q&A pairs. The criteria for bumping by the bot are criteria for Q&A pairs ignored by community members in the past. So look at the question and answers the same way you read and evaluate new questions and answers.

The Community bot bumps Q&A pairs where the answer has score 0. In case of multiple answers, the highest scored answer has score 0. Excluded are Q&A pairs with accepted answer, closed questions and questions with negative score.

So what can we do to remove these Q&A pairs from this 'ignored zone' so they are not bumped over and over?

If a positive score of the question is not deserved, downvote the question. Sometimes bad questions have a random upvote. And if the question is incomplete or off topic, vote/flag it to close as usual.

If the question is OK, then it deserves a good answer. If there is one, upvote it. If the answer is not good, downvote it. If you can write a good answer, please write it. And if the existing answer with score 0 is 'not an answer' which got under our radar, flag it.

Comment: I agree with Juraj here. Often these bumped questions actually have a reasonable answer,  but no-one has voted for the answer. Voting for the answer(s) can help.

Comment: The asking persons could need a bit more motivation to accept answeres as well. The style of asking (so many low-quality questions here on arduino) sometimes shows they have not yet grasped how SE is intended to work :(

Comment: "The Community bot bumps Q&A pairs where the answer has score 0." Even if it has an accepted answer? Why did the bot bring back this one? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78552/wiring-up-an-esp-01-to-nano   Even if all of those upvotes were made since it was brought back, it already had an accepted answer.

Comment: @JRobert, it wasn't bumped. it was edited 2 days ago. you can see the history with the 'time back' icon below the vote buttons

Comment: I see - thank you.